# What is the best practice to implement advanced search using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search

I am using two different ways to implement an advanced search where each approach has their advantages and disadvantages.

The user can perform an advanced search using 3 parameters (name, familyname, and mobile).

The first way I tried is to check which of those parameters are provided by the user; that requires me to do 8 `if` & `else` checks  (2 ^ number of parameters) and in each conditions I write a separate query which accepts the corresponding parameters, for example if the user has entered name & family name the where clause of the query will look like this:

```
where(x=>x.name.contains(name) && x.familyname.contains(familyname))
```

or in another case if the user has entered only the mobile the where clause of the query will look like this :

```
where(x=>x.mobile==mobile)
```

the advantage of this way is that I hit the databse once but the disadvantage is that I have to write a lot more code.

The second way I tried is that I declared an `IQueryable<>` object and I feed data into It with no condition at first and then I check search parameters one by one and if any of them has value I filter the `IQueryable` with that value and at last I perform a `.ToList()`.  This way has the advantage of much less code but hits the database twice which is a problem.

Here is a code sample of the second way:

```
List<ShoppingCardForGridView> list_ShoppingCardForGridView = 
    new List<ShoppingCardForGridView>();
IQueryable<ShoppingCardForGridView> outQuery = 
    from x in db.ShoppingCards
    orderby x.TFDateBackFromBank descending
    where x.TFIsPaymentCompleted == true
    select new ShoppingCardForGridView
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        TFCustomerFullName = 
            x.Customer.TFName + " " + x.Customer.TFFamilyName,
        TFDateBackFromBank = x.TFDateBackFromBank.Value,
        TFIsDelivered = x.TFIsDelivered,
        TFItemsPriceToPay = x.TFItemsPriceToPay,
        TFDateBackFromBankPersian = x.TFDateBackFromBankPersian

    };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerFullName))
{
    outQuery = outQuery.Where(x => 
        x.TFCustomerFullName.Contains(CustomerFullName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsDelivered))
{
    bool deliveryStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(IsDelivered);
    outQuery = outQuery.Where(x => x.TFIsDelivered == deliveryStatus);
}
list_ShoppingCardForGridView = outQuery.ToList();
```

I wonder if there is any better way or a best practice to perform an advanced search using entityframework?

Comment: I think this might be better for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You need to build an expression tree.

Comment: @SLaks any code sample or good tutorial ?

Comment: I'm failing to see how you're hitting the DB twice.  There is only one iteration there.

Comment: @SLaks I don't see any need for that.  The code that he already has is simpler than manually building the expression and equally effective.

Comment: @Servy In the second way when the query is performed :  IQueryable<ShoppingCardForGridView> outQuery = from x in db.ShoppingCards ... It hits the databse once and in the line : list_ShoppingCardForGridView = outQuery.ToList(); where a .ToList() is performed the database is hit again . am I right ?

Comment: @Karamafrooz That is false.  The first line doesn't execute any query at all.

Comment: No, it only hits the database when ToList() is executed.

Comment: side note, there's no point in creating a new list at the start of the method.  You never use that list, you just throw it away without ever adding anything to it.  Instead just delete that line entirely and define the local variable for the first time on that last line, since you don't need it earlier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're *not* hitting the database multiple times with your second solution.  Remember that an `IQueryable` object is *a query itself, not the results of a query*.  Execution is deferred until the query is actually iterated.  Conditionally appending multiple `Where` clauses based on various `if` checks is changing the query itself, not processing the results of the query (since there are no results at that point in time).

You can use a profiler on your database to verify that only one query is being executed, and that the one query contains all of the filtering in that one go.

This is a reasonably common pattern; I've used it on a number of instances for making custom search pages.

Comment: So is my second way a best practice ?

Comment: @Karamafrooz It's a great way to do it that is clearly correct, equally effective, extensible, and easy to write, unlike the first which is very cumbersome, error prone, and not extensible.  That should make the decision rather obvious.